# Julia BoundsError when deleting items of a list while iterating over it

Tags: julia

I would like to iterate over a list and occasionally delete items of said list. Below a toy example:

```
function delete_item!(myarray, item)
    deleteat!(myarray, findin(myarray, [item]))
end

n = 1000
myarray = [i for i = 1:n];

for a in myarray
    if a%2 == 0
        delete_item!(myarray, a)
    end
end
```

However I get error:

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 500-element Array{Int64,1} at index [502]
```

How can I fix it (as efficiently as possible)?

Additional information. The above seems like a silly example, in my original problem I have a list of agents which interact. Therefore I am not sure if iterating over a copy would be the best solution. For example:

```
#creating my agent
mutable struct agent <: Any
    id::Int
end

function delete_item!(myarray::Array{agent, 1}, item::agent)
    deleteat!(myarray, findin(myarray, [item]))
end 

#having my list of agents
n = 1000
myarray = agent[agent(i) for i = 1:n];

#trying to remove agents from list while having them interact
for a in myarray
    #agent does stuff
    if a.id%2 == 0 #if something happens remove
        delete_item!(myarray, a)
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you explored filter!() ? It is illustrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298809/delete-element-in-an-array-for-julia

Comment: Yes, although I thought when deleting one item at a time it is more efficient to use deleteat!()?

Comment: Thanks for posting this question — it prompted https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/27079 to improve Julia's behavior here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no single answer to this question as most efficient approach depends on the logic of the whole model (in particular do other agents' actions depend on the fact that some entry is actually deleted from an array).

In most cases the following approach should be the simplest (I am leaving `findin` which is inefficient but I understand that you may have duplicates in `myarray` in general):

```
n = 1000
myarray = [i for i = 1:n];
keep = trues(n)

for (i, a) in enumerate(myarray)
    keep[i] || continue # do not process an agent that is marked for deletion
    if a%2 == 0 # here application logic might also need to check keep in some cases
        keep[findin(myarray, [a])] = false
    end
end

myarray = myarray[keep]
```

If for some reason you really need to delete elements of `myarray` in each iteration here is how you can do it:

```
n = 1000
myarray = [i for i = 1:n];

i = 1
while i <= length(myarray)
    a = myarray[i]
    if a%2 == 0
        todelete = findin(myarray, [a])
        i -= count(x -> x < i, todelete) # if myarray has duplicates of a you have to move the counter back
        deleteat!(myarray, todelete)
    else
        i += 1
    end
end
```

In general the code you give will not be very fast (e.g. if you know `myarray` does not contain duplicates it can be much simpler - and I guess you can).

EDIT: Here is how you can implement both versions if you know you do not have duplicates (you can simply use agent's index - observe that we can also avoid unnecessary checks):

```
n = 1000
myarray = [i for i = 1:n];
keep = trues(n)

for (i, a) in enumerate(myarray)
    if a%2 == 0 # here application logic might also need to check keep in some cases
        keep[i] = false
    end
end

myarray = myarray[keep]
```

If for some reason you really need to delete elements of `myarray` in each iteration here is how you can do it:

```
n = 1000
myarray = [i for i = 1:n];

i = 1
while i <= length(myarray)
    a = myarray[i]
    if a%2 == 0
        deleteat!(myarray, i)
    else
        i += 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Just curious about your remark about "findin" inefficiency, from this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298809/delete-element-in-an-array-for-julia) I thought it was the best way to remove a specific element. I actually have no duplicates in my array list, so if there is a better alternative to "findin" I would love to use it.

Comment: I have added example implementations in the answer. You can see that they need to do much less work.