# How to delete a selected element in a range construct in Julia?

Tags: julia

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298809/delete-element-in-an-array-for-julia) I found that in a range construct one cannot find and replace its elements via array functions... How can be do it anyway?

Suppose I want to delete the elements `2,6,7,8,13,19` in `range(1, step=1, stop=21)`. Or more generally, suppose `a` is a random array that contains numbers in the range `[1,21]` and one wants to delete these elementes in the given range.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot delete from a range object, since that is immutable, but you can `filter` it:

```
julia> filter(x -> x ∉ [2,6,7,8,13,19], a)
15-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  3
  4
  5
  9
 10
 11
 12
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 20
 21
```

However, if `a` is a "real" array, you can use `filter!` to operate in-place.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that if often convenient is to use InvertedIndices.jl package which exports `Not` and you can just use indexing:

```
julia> r = 1:21
1:21

julia> x = [2,6,7,8,13,19]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  6
  7
  8
 13
 19

julia> r[Not(x)]
15-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  3
  4
  5
  9
 10
 11
 12
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 20
 21
```